# Unable to record audio with Pyaudio for Raspberry Pi 4 on a separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, audio, recording

I have been able to get audio recording working in a single thread but can't seem to get audio to record in a separate thread.  It throws a Errno -9981 Input Overflowed for Pyaudio. I'm pretty stuck trying to record audio while having the controls remain unblocked on another thread. I have tried setting the buffer size to as high as 8192 to no avail as well.  Any help would be much appreciated

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np

def thread1(threadname, q):    
    form_1 = pyaudio.paInt16 # 16-bit resolution
    chans = 2 # 1 channel
    samp_rate = 44100 # 44.1kHz sampling rate
    chunk = 4096 # 2^12 samples for buffer
    record_secs = 3 # seconds to record
    dev_index = 0 # device index found by p.get_device_info_by_index(ii)
    wav_output_filename = 'AudioTest.wav' # name of .wav file
    
    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio() # create pyaudio instantiation
    
    stream = audio.open(format = form_1,rate = samp_rate,channels = chans, \
                    input_device_index = dev_index,input = True, \
                    frames_per_buffer=chunk)
    record = 0
    #Runs until thread exit condition of 2
    while record != 2:
        while record == 0:
            if q.empty() == False:
                record = q.get()
            #print("Q Get")
            #print(record)
        #If not on exit condition, start recording
        if record != 2:
            frames = []
            while record == 1:
                data = stream.read(chunk)
                frames.append(data)
                if q.empty() == False:
                    record = q.get()
                #print("Recording")
                #print(record)
            wavefile = wave.open(wav_output_filename,'wb')
            wavefile.setnchannels(chans)
            wavefile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(form_1))
            wavefile.setframerate(samp_rate)
            wavefile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
            wavefile.close()
            print("Wav file saved")
    print("Recording thread closing")
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()
    print("Stream ended")
    return # End Program

def thread2(threadname, q):
    #Not recording
    q.put(0)
    time.sleep(5)
    #Recording
    q.put(1)
    time.sleep(5)
    #Not recording
    q.put(0)
    time.sleep(3)
    #End thread
    print("Ending thread 1")
    q.put(2) # Ends thread 1
    time.sleep(5)
    print("End")

queue = Queue()
thread1 = Thread( target=thread1, args=("Thread-1", queue) )
thread2 = Thread( target=thread2, args=("Thread-2", queue) )

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```